# save variable argument list for fprintf calls

Tags: multithreading, c++11, variadic-functions

I am writing a heavy multi threaded [>170 threads] c++11 program. Each thread is logging information into **one** file used by all threads. For performance reasons I want to create a *log* thread which is writing the information via `fprintf()` into the global file. I have no idea how to organize the structure into which the *worker* threads are writing the information which can be then read by the *log* thread.

Why do I not call `sprintf()` in each *worker* thread and then just provide the output buffer to the *log* thread? For the formatted output into the log file I am using a `locale` in the `fprintf()` functions which is different than in the rest of the thread. Therefore I would have to switch and lock/guard permanently the `xprintf()` calls in order to differ the `locale` output.
In the *log* thread I have one `locale` setting used for the whole output while the *worker* threads have their `locale` version.

Another reason for the *log* thread is that I have to "group" the output otherwise the information from each *worker* thread would not be in a block:

Wrong:

```
Information A Thread #1
Information A Thread #2
Information B Thread #1
Information B Thread #2
```

Correct:

```
Information A Thread #1
Information B Thread #1
Information A Thread #2
Information B Thread #2
```

In order to achieve this grouping I have to guard the output in each *worker*  thread which is slowing the thread execution time.

How can I save the `va_list` into a structure that way it can be read by the *log* thread and passed back to `fprintf()`?

Comment: Why should changing the locale be any kind of hassle?

Comment: If you care about performance, why do you have 170 threads? Are they all active at once? Do you have a massively parallel CPU?

Comment: How about using `vfprintf` and passing `va_list`?

Comment: @Deduplicator: Good point. OK; this is not the problem but grouping the output with the `lock_guard` is slowing the threads.

Comment: @Inspired: But how do I save this `va_list` into a structure that I can use it in the _log_ thread?

Comment: @Cameron: No, they are not active at once. I have a threshold value of  32 concurrently running threads and therefore it is very important a thread can finish very fast in order to wake up another thread. The log  information is important but not at the same time while the thread is running. Therefore I want to split the calculating task time from the logging time because it is for me "wasted" time.

Comment: The only sane way to do things I see is: 1. print it into a buffer in the worker. 2. Log it in the logger. The logger can apply any kind of grouping it wants.

Comment: How many different argument types do you have?  If you don't need much more than `int`, `double` and maybe some string, a `std::vector` of some `union` (or something like `boost::variant`) could do the job.

Comment: @5gon12eder: yes, but how do I concate then the different parameters into a variable argument list in order to be used in a printf() function?

Comment: Any chance of getting rid of the per-thread locale functionality and just using a single (non-changeable) locale for all threads?  I think that would make life easier for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how this would be done easily using the legacy C `vprintf` with `va_list`s.  As you want to pass things around between threads, sooner or later you will need to use the heap in some way.

Below is a solution that uses [Boost.Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/format/doc/format.html) for the formatting and [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/variant.html) for parameter passing.  The example is complete and working if you concatenate the following code blocks in order.  If you compile with GCC, you need to pass the `-pthread` linker flag.  And of course, you'll also need the two Boost libraries which are header-only, however.  Here are the headers we will use.

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <locale>
#include <mutex>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
```

At first, we need some mechanism to asynchronously execute some tasks, in this case, print our logging messages.  Since the concept is general, I use an “abstract” base class `Spooler` for this.  Its code is based on Herb Sutter's talk *“Lock-Free Programming (or, Juggling Razor Blades)”* on CppCon 2014 ([part 1](http://youtu.be/c1gO9aB9nbs), [part 2](http://youtu.be/CmxkPChOcvw)).  I'm not going into detail about this code because it is mostly scaffolding not directly related to your question and I assume you already have this piece of functionality in place.  My `Spooler` uses a `std::list` protected by a `std::mutex` as a task queue.  It might be worthwhile to consider using a lock-free data structure instead.

```
class Spooler
{
private:

  bool done_ {};
  std::list<std::function<void(void)>> queue_ {};
  std::mutex mutex_ {};
  std::condition_variable condvar_ {};
  std::thread worker_ {};

public:

  Spooler() : worker_ {[this](){ work(); }}
  {
  }

  ~Spooler()
  {
    auto poison = [this](){ done_ = true; };
    this->submit(std::move(poison));
    if (this->worker_.joinable())
      this->worker_.join();
  }

protected:

  void
  submit(std::function<void(void)> task)
  {
    // This is basically a push_back but avoids potentially blocking
    // calls while in the critical section.
    decltype(this->queue_) tmp {std::move(task)};
    {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck {this->mutex_};
      this->queue_.splice(this->queue_.cend(), tmp);
    }
    this->condvar_.notify_all();
  }

private:

  void
  work()
  {
    do
      {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck {this->mutex_};
        while (this->queue_.empty())
          this->condvar_.wait(lck);
        const auto task = std::move(this->queue_.front());
        this->queue_.pop_front();
        lck.unlock();
        task();
      }
    while (!this->done_);
  }
};
```

From the `Spooler`, we now derive a `Logger` that (privately) inherits its asynchronous capabilities from the `Spooler` and adds the logging specific functionality.  It has only one function member called `log` that takes as parameters a format string and zero or more arguments to format into it as a `std::vector` of `boost::variant`s.

Unfortunately, this limits us to a fixed number of types we can support but that shouldn't be a large problem since the C `printf` doesn't support arbitrary types either.  For the sake of this example, I'm only using `int` and `double` but you can extend the list with `std::string`s, `void *` pointers or what have you.

The `log` function constructs a lambda expression that creates a `boost::format` object, feeds it all the arguments and then writes it to `std::log` or wherever you want the formatted message to go.

The constructor of `boost::format` has an overload that accepts the format string and a locale.  You might be interested in this one since you have mentioned setting a custom locale in the comments.  The usual constructor only takes a single argument, the format string.

Note how all formatting and outputting is done on the spooler's thread.

```
class Logger : Spooler
{
 public:

  void
  log(const std::string& fmt,
      const std::vector<boost::variant<int, double>>& args)
  {
    auto task = [fmt, args](){
      boost::format msg {fmt, std::locale {"C"}};  // your locale here
      for (const auto& arg : args)
        msg % arg;  // feed the next argument
      std::clog << msg << std::endl;  // print the formatted message
    };
    this->submit(std::move(task));
  }
};
```

This is all it takes.  We can now use the `Logger` like in this example.  It is important that all worker threads are `join()` ed before the `Logger` is destructed or it won't process all messages.

```
int
main()
{
  Logger logger {};
  std::vector<std::thread> threads {};
  std::random_device rnddev {};
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
      const auto seed = rnddev();
      auto task = [&logger, i, seed](){
        std::default_random_engine rndeng {seed};
        std::uniform_real_distribution<double> rnddist {0.0, 0.5};
        for (double p = 0.0; p < 1.0; p += rnddist(rndeng))
          logger.log("thread #%d is %6.2f %% done", {i, 100.0 * p});
        logger.log("thread #%d has completed its work", {i});
      };
      threads.emplace_back(std::move(task));
    }
  for (auto& thread : threads)
    thread.join();
}
```

Possible output:

```
thread #1 is   0.00 % done
thread #0 is   0.00 % done
thread #0 is  26.84 % done
thread #0 is  76.15 % done
thread #3 is   0.00 % done
thread #0 has completed its work
thread #3 is  34.70 % done
thread #3 is  78.92 % done
thread #3 is  91.89 % done
thread #3 has completed its work
thread #1 is  26.98 % done
thread #1 is  73.84 % done
thread #1 has completed its work
thread #2 is   0.00 % done
thread #2 is  10.17 % done
thread #2 is  29.85 % done
thread #2 is  79.03 % done
thread #2 has completed its work
```

Comment: Please give me few days to check it out. I am a C++ beginner and this is lot of new code for me...

Comment: I accepted your answer because it works that far. For me I could not use it [I do not use the `boost` library; I need the thousand separator which makes the formatting more complex, ..]. I wrote now my own version.