# Synchronizing output to std::cout

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have an application wherein several threads write to `std::cout` and I was looking for a simple solution to prevent data being sent to `std::cout` from being garbled up.

For example, if I have 2 threads and both output:

```
std::cout << "Hello" << ' ' << "from" << ' ' << "thread" << ' ' << n << '\n';
```

I might see something like:

```
HelloHello from  fromthread  2
thread 1
```

What I would like to see is:

```
Hello from thread 2
Hello from thread 1
```

The order in which the lines are displayed is not very important, as long as they don't get intermixed.

I came up with the following fairly simple implementation:

```
class syncstream : public std::ostringstream {
public:
    using std::ostringstream::ostringstream;

    syncstream& operator<<(std::ostream&  (*pf)(std::ostream&) ) { pf(*this); return *this; }
    syncstream& operator<<(std::ios&      (*pf)(std::ios&)     ) { pf(*this); return *this; }
    syncstream& operator<<(std::ios_base& (*pf)(std::ios_base&)) { pf(*this); return *this; }

    template<typename T>
    syncstream& operator<<(T&& token) {
        static_cast<std::ostringstream&>(*this) << std::forward<T>(token);
        return *this;
    }
};

inline std::ostream& operator&&(std::ostream& s, const syncstream& g) { return s << g.str(); }
#define synced(stream) stream && syncstream()
```

Sorry about the macro.

So, now in my threads I can do:

```
synced(std::cout) << "Hello"  << ' ' << "from" << ' ' << "thread" << ' ' << n << '\n';
```

I wrote the above because of my initial misunderstanding of §27.4.1. But, surprisingly it works very well.

I wrote the following test case:

```
void proc(int n) {
    synced(std::cout) << "Hello" << ' ' << "world" << ' ' << "from" << ' ' << "thread" << ' ' << n << '\n';
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for(int n = 0; n < 1000; ++n) threads.push_back(std::thread(std::bind(proc, n)));

    for(std::thread& thread: threads) thread.join();
    return 0;
}
```

(full version [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7261620112d509ea)) and ran it with both g++ 4.8.3 and clang++ 3.5.1 (with libstdc++ and libc++) on my system.

Testing was done with a [script](https://bpaste.net/show/9d5879ade46f), which runs the test case 1000 times generating 1 million output lines and then parses the output for any garbled lines.

I *cannot* make it **not** work (ie, produce garbled lines).

So my question is:

*Why does the above implementation work?*

Comment: Cannot see where you use `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(true)`?

Comment: @Walter, I set it in the [test case](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f931f954a15f0fdd) in `main` function

Comment: Why do you need the `&&` operator at all? I can only see it used in the `synced` macro, which could instead directly return `(stream << syncstream().str())`, couldn't it?

Comment: I want the `syncstream` to accumulate all `<<` to right of it. Otherwise `(stream << syncstream().str())` will expand into `(std::cout << syncstream().str()) << "Hello" << ' ' << "world" ...`, which will output empty `syncstream` to `std::cout` and then the remaining stuff

Comment: Your testcase should be in the question. It should _be_ the question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I was trying to avoid tl;dr but let me add it to the question

Comment: Interesting reading: [N3665](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3665.html). This made it through LWG but was voted down in the full committee.

Comment: @T.C., heh, that's exactly what I did :)

Comment: @T.C. Probably because it isn't useful.

Comment: Have you tried using longer strings (say, more than `BUFSIZ` long)?

Comment: @T.C. I haven't... FWIW `BUFSIZ` is 8192. At that length no line will be readable anyway :) Let me try to work a test case  for this.

Comment: @T.C. went up to 8503 character long line in the form: `synced(std::cout) << "[" << "1234567890" << "1234567890" ... repeated 850 times ... << "]" << '\n';` Still works!

Answer (score 2):

This appears thread-safe in the sense of not producing garbled lines, *provided each output ends with a new line*. However, it does change the nature of the stream output, in particular with respect to flushing.

1 `synced(std::cerr)` will be buffered (into your `syncstream`), while `std::cerr` is never buffered.

2 there is no guarantee that

```
synced(std::cout) << "a=" << 128 << std::endl;
```

actually flushes the buffer of `std::cout`, since all `std::cout` gets is the string `"a=128\n"`.

A stronger interpretation of thread-safe would be that the order of output reflects the order, if any, of output calls. That is if

```
synced(std::cout) << "a=" << 128 << std::endl;
```

on thread `A` is guaranteed (by means of locks for example) to preceed the same call on thread `B`, then the output of `A` should always preceed that of `B`. I don't think that your code achieves that.

Comment: It can produce garbled lines, at least according to the standard.  (I suspect that it never will in practice.)

Comment: Walter, your both points are correct, but (un)fortunately neither one is important in my particular case. :)

Answer (score 2):

With regards to thread safety: it's thread safe in the sense that it
won't cause a data race.  But only as long as the target is one of the
standard stream objects (`std::cout`, etc.), and only as long as they
remain synched with stdio.  That's all the standard guarantees.  And
even then, you can still end up with interleaved characters.

I've had to deal with this problem a lot in the past.  My solution has
always been a wrapper class, with a pointer to the actual
`std::ostream`, and a template:

```
template <typename T>
SynchedOutput& operator<<( T const& obj )
{
    if ( myStream != nullptr ) {
        (*myStream) << obj;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

The constructor of `SynchedOutput` then acquires a mutex lock, and the
destructor frees it, so you can write:

```
SynchedOutput( stream, mutex ) << ...;
```

(In my case, I was returning the temporary from a function, and was
doing so before C++11 and its move semantics, so my code was a bit more
complicated; I had to support copy, and keep track of the count of the
copies, so that I could unlock when the last one was destructed.  Today,
just implement move semantics, and no copy, if you want to return the
instance from a function.))

The issue here is ensuring that everyone is using the same mutex.  One
possibility might be to have the constructor look up the mutex in an
`std::map` indexed on the address of the stream object.  This lookup
requires a global lock, so you can even construct a new mutex if the
stream object doesn't have one.  The real issue is ensuring that the
mutex is removed from the map when the stream is destructed.

Comment: I initially set out to do something similar, but few things hampered it: 1. gcc streams won't support move semantics until gcc-5 is out (I am still on gcc 4.8.3); and 2) Herb Sutter says blocking is evil ;) I will rephrase my question slightly, because the main thing I wanted to find out, why does the above work.

Comment: @InnocentBystander I have recently posted a minimum-blocking solution as [an answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28640260/save-variable-argument-list-for-fprintf-calls/28641381#28641381).  You might find it useful, too.

Comment: @5gon12eder, looks decent [Herb](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-Concurrency-and-Parallelism) would like this a lot. :)

Comment: @InnocentBystander Yes, as mentioned in my other post, it is inspired by code I have seen in one of his talks.

Comment: @InnocentBystander I did this long before C++11 was available; it does mean that you have to count the copies.  And regardless of what Herb says (although I doubt that he says anything quite that simplistic), blocking isn't evil; it's necessary.  Blocking too long can be a problem; if that's the case here, write your own streambuf to collect the data, and then output it in one go in the destructor.  (I do this in my logging classes, because the actual output is often sent as an email, or to syslog.  Both of which require a single "output" for each "message".)

Comment: @JamesKanze, I was mostly kidding about Herb. :) But my question still stands. My impl works without any sort of blocking and I dunno why. Even with data larger than `BUFSIZ` (see my answers to T.C.'s comments). And unless someone proves me wrong, I see little reason to add mutexes and more code. :)

Comment: @InnocentBystander The mutexes are present; they're implicit when outputting to one of the standard output objects (`std::cout`, etc.), as long as these remain synchronized to stdio.  The difference is that you don't control when and how often they are taken.  And the issue is precisely: they are only present when outputting to one of the standard iostream objects, and only as long as it is synchronized.  Most of the time, you'll also want to be able to output through an arbitrary `std::ostream`, at which point, your solution won't work.