# How to launch multiple threads and each thread working on different files?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread

I have a single thread application which is sending a file to other server by calling `send_new_file`

```
void send_new_file_command::start_sending_file()
{
    m_thread = thread(&send_new_file_command::execute_file, this);
}

void send_new_file_command::execute_file()
{
    for (auto it = files_need_to_send.begin(); it != files_need_to_send.end() && !is_complete(); ++it)
    {
        {
            std::unique_lock<spinning_lock> guard(lock_obj);
            m_current_file = *it;
        }
        // send a file.
        // I want to call this in parallel
        send_new_file(*it);
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can have multiple threads and each thread sending one file each. As an example let's say we have 4 threads and thread 1,2,3,4 will send different files in parallel. I want to call `send_new_file` in parallel?

I am using `std::thread`. I was looking at thread example on how can I do this in C++ but got confuse how can I divide number of files per thread here and make sure each thread works on subset of files.

```
  std::vector<std::thread> threads;
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    threads.push_back(std::thread(send_new_file(*it)));
```

My background is in Java so slightly confuse how to do this in C++ using std::thread.

Comment: I'm confused what your problem is.  Couldn't you simply have each thread grab files from a list until that list eventually becomes empty which the threads realize and shut down?  Can you show (simplified) code how you would solve this in Java?  It should translate to C++11 quite straight-forwardly.  Btw, what is this lock good for?

Comment: When you say "send new file"... where are you sending the file to, and where is it coming from?


For instance, if you are sending all of these files over the network and you can get them from memory, you are most likely capped by the speed of the network, so sending multiple files at once won't speed up your total throughput.


Also, if you are getting the files from the same HDD, reading them all at once could cause HDD thrashing on non-SSDs, and will greatly reduce how quickly you can read them. So your best bet is to read one contiguous file at a time.


Multi-threaded isn't always faster.

Comment: We have SSD's running with all raid0 no mirroring. I wanted to try out this to see whether it improves anything or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly simple approach using a work queue.  You can concatenate the code snippets into a self-contained program.  We will use the following standard library headers.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
```

First, we define a function that takes a single file name and sends it wherever it should go to.  I'll simulate this by simply writing it to `/dev/null`.

```
void
send_file(const std::string& filename)
{
  std::ifstream istr {};
  std::ofstream ostr {};
  std::string line {};
  istr.exceptions(std::ifstream::badbit);
  ostr.exceptions(std::ofstream::badbit);
  istr.open(filename);
  ostr.open("/dev/null");
  while (std::getline(istr, line))
    ostr << line << '\n';
}
```

Next, we define a function that takes a pointer to a `std::vector` of files that still need to be sent and another pointer to a `std::mutex` that is supposed to protect that vector.  I'm using pointers instead of references because this allows me to create the `std::thread`s simpler later on.  You don't need to do this, if you don't like it.

```
int
send_files(std::vector<std::string> *const files_p, std::mutex *const mutex_p)
{
  auto count = 0;
  while (true)
    {
      std::string next {};
      {
        const std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck {*mutex_p};
        if (files_p->empty())  // nothing left to do
          return count;
        next = std::move(files_p->back());
        files_p->pop_back();
      }
      send_file(next);
      count += 1;
    }
}
```

The important thing is that we don't hold the lock while the actual work of sending the file is performed.  Otherwise, we would completely kill concurrency.  I was also careful not to allocate any memory while holding to the lock.  Usually, you will see `std::list`s used as work queues and `std::condition_variable`s to signal when a change to the queue has occurred.  I have posted code showing this in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28641381/1392132) some time ago.
  However, in this simple case, the queue is only ever removed from so a `std::vector` is a perfect fit.

Finally, we use what we have in a simple program that creates one thread per hardware concurrency unit and asks these threads to send all files named in the command line arguments.  Note that, as written, this will process the list in reversed order.  It is trivial to change, though, if this is an issue for you.

```
int
main(int argc, char * * argv)
{
  const auto nthreads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
  std::mutex mutex {};
  std::vector<std::thread> threads {};
  std::vector<std::string> files {};
  files.reserve(argc - 1);
  for (auto i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    files.push_back(argv[i]);
  threads.reserve(nthreads);
  for (auto t = 0U; t < nthreads; ++t)
    threads.emplace_back(send_files, &files, &mutex);
  for (auto t = 0U; t < nthreads; ++t)
    threads[t].join();
}
```

Comment: I avoid using `const` for `nthreads`. You should check if the return value is 0 (it is possible) and assign a value of 1 or something similar. Otherwise in a case of 0 your program will not really do much.

Answer (score 1):

## A first approach

There's a first simple solution:

- your class contains a vector of files to be processed
- only one thread manages this vector through the function `execute_file()`
- this function creates as many threads as needed, each processing one file
- at the end, all the threads are joined (mandatory)

The code would look like that:

```
struct send_new_file_command {
    vector<string> files_need_to_send;
public:
    send_new_file_command(vector<string> f) : files_need_to_send(f) {}
    void execute_file();
};
void send_new_file_command::execute_file()
{
    vector<thread> exec;
    for(auto it = files_need_to_send.begin(); it != files_need_to_send.end(); ++it)
    {
        exec.push_back(thread(send_new_file, *it));
    }
    for(auto &e : exec)
        e.join();
}
```

The code could be tested with the following:

```
void send_new_file(string x) { // simulator 
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        cout << x << endl;
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(500));
    }
}
int main() {
    vector<string>vs{"a", "b", "c", "d"};
    send_new_file_command sfc(vs);
    sfc.execute_file();
    return 0;
}
```

This solution is very simple.  It has two major drawbacks:

- it may launch much more threads than your hardware can manage.  So that only a handful of them truly run concurrently.
- on thread is dedicated to a file.  FIf it's a short file and the thread is free again, it will not be reused.

## Other solutions

There are plenty of other solutions. For example:

- A variant of this one, would to launch a fixed number of threads, each looking in the vector of files to be processed for the next item, as soon as it's ready.  You'd then need to introduce strong locking.
- Instead of using raw threads, you could consider futures, launching `std::async(std::launch::async, send_new_file, *it);`

Answer (score 1):

Performance-wise the best way to do it:

1. declare a counter variable using `std::atomic<int>`
2. create the threads in a vector, array, whatever
3. call join for every thread

The main function of the thread then accesses and increments the shared counter and saves the result in a local variable in a loop:

```
std::atomic<int> counter = 0;
for(int j = 0;j<4;j++)
{
    threads.push_back(std::thread([&](){
        for(int i; (i = counter++) < size;)//the counter variable must be atomic!
        {
            do_work(i);
        }
    }));
}

for(int j = 0;j<4;j++)
    threads[i].join();
```